# Tableau distinct values in dimension

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation

I am trying to calculate orders per distinct customer numbers, but in dimension CUSTOMER number there are duplicates. So i need to use something with distinct values.

if {fixed([Customer number]):COUNTD([Order Id (copy)])}>=4 then "Big gamers"

else "Small gamers"

end

Comment: What is the question? What result do you want?

Comment: There ae duplicates in dimension Customer number - so i need to agregate this(i need only distinct values).  As now i am getting incorrect results. Question is : how i can calculate orders per customer

Comment: If you drag customer number to rows and then "orders" to rows (assuming there is a count or value field with that data) then table will, by default, give to aggregate order total for each customer.

Comment: Yesy but, i need to split the customers for those who have 3 or more orders. And for this i need to have aggregated dimension, as formula I am trying to use now does not work

Comment: Do it in two steps so you can see where errors might happen. Use the formula `fixed [Customer Number]: countd([Order ID]}` to create a field called `orders per customer` and then create a second filed to do the grouping logic (like `if [orders per customer]>3 then 'Big' else 'Small' end` ). That way you can see where any errors arise.

Comment: Thank you very much! So finally i used {FIXED [Customer id] : MIN([Customer id])} for distinct and then groups. Thank you for your helpful advices